# Conversion system for variants

Tags: compiler-construction, casting, language-design, compiler-theory, variant

I have written a variant class, which will be used as the main type in a dynamic language, that will ultimately allow 256 different types of value (header is an unsigned byte, only 20 are actually used). I now want to implement casting/converting between types.

My initial thought was a lookup table, but the shear amount of memory that would need makes it impractical to implement.

What are the alternatives? Right now I am considering a further three methods from research and suggestions from other people:

1. Group the types into larger subsets, such as numeric or collection or other.
2. Make a conversion interface that has CanCast(from, to) and Cast(Variant) methods and allow classes that implement that interface to be added to a list, that can then be checked to see if any of the conversion classes can do the cast.
3. Similar to (1) but make several master types, and casting is a two step process from the original type to the master type and then again to the final type.

What would be the best system?

Edit: I have added the bounty as I am still unsure on the best system, the current answer is very good, and definitely got my +1 but there must be people out there who have done this and can say what the best method is.

Comment: Another posibility I didn't mention is using third party implementations. I've done some background reading into COM VARIANTs but I don't really want to do that for a number of reasons (mostly that I want to do it, and I'm not sure that a union of all possible types is the best way to do it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My system is very "heavy" (lots of code), but very fast, and very feature rich (cross-platform C++).  I'm not sure how far you would want to go with your design, but here's the biggest parts of what I did:

**`DatumState`** - Class holding an "enum" for "type", plus native value, which is a "union" among all the primitive types, including `void*`.  This class is uncoupled from all types, and can be used for any native/primitive types, and "reference to" `void*` type.  Since the "`enum`" also has "`VALUE_OF`" and "`REF_TO`" context, this class can present as "wholly containing" a `float` (or some primitive type), or "referencing-but-not-owning" a `float` (or some primitive type).  (I actually have "`VALUE_OF`", "`REF_TO`", and "`PTR_TO`" contexts so I can logically store a *value*, a *reference-that-cannot-be-null*, or a *pointer-that-may-be-null-or-not*, and which I know I need to *delete-or-not*.)

**`Datum`** - Class wholly containing a **`DatumState`**, but which expands its interface to accommodate various "well-known" types (like `MyDate`, `MyColor`, `MyFileName`, etc.)  These well-known types are actually stored in the `void*` inside the `DatumState` member.  However, because the "`enum`" portion of the `DatumState` has the "`VALUE_OF`" and "`REF_TO`" context, it can represent a "`pointer-to-MyDate`" or "`value-of-MyDate`".

**`DatumStateHandle`** - A helper template class parameterized with a (well-known) type (like `MyDate`, `MyColor`, `MyFileName`, etc.)  This is the accessor used by `Datum` to extract state from the well-known type.  The default implementation works for most classes, but any class with specific semantics for access merely overrides its specific template parameterization/implementation for one or more member functions in this template class.

**`Macros, helper functions, and some other supporting stuff`** - To simplify "adding" of well-known types to my `Datum`/`Variant`, I found it convenient to centralize logic into a few macros, provide some support functions like operator overloading, and establish some other conventions in my code.

As a "side-effect" of this implementation, I got tons of benefits, including reference and value semantics, options for "null" on all types, and support for heterogeneous containers for all types.

For example, you can create a set of integers and index them:

```
int my_ints[10];
Datum d(my_ints, 10/*count*/);
for(long i = 0; i < d.count(); ++i)
{
  d[i] = i;
}
```

Similarly, some data types are indexed by strings, or by enums:

```
MyDate my_date = MyDate::GetDateToday();
Datum d(my_date);
cout << d["DAY_OF_WEEK"] << endl;
cout << d[MyDate::DAY_OF_WEEK] << endl; // alternative
```

I can store sets-of-items (natively), or sets-of-`Datum`s (wrapping each item).  For either case, I can "unwrap" recursively:

```
MyDate my_dates[10];
Datum d(my_dates, 10/*count*/);
for(long i = 0; i < d.count(); ++i)
{
  cout << d[i][MyDate::DAY_OF_WEEK] << endl;
}
```

One might argue my "`REF_TO`" and "`VALUE_OF`" semantics are overkill, but they were essential for the "set-unwrapping".

I've done this "`Variant`" thing with nine different designs, and my current is the "heaviest" (most code), but the one I like the best (almost the fastest with a pretty small object footprint), and I've deprecated the other eight designs for my use.

The "downsides" to my design are:

1. Objects are accessed through
   `static_cast<>()` from a `void*`
   (type-safe and fairly fast, but
   indirection is required; but,
   side-effect is that design supports
   storage of "`null`".)
2. Compiles are longer because of the
   well-known types that are exposed
   through the `Datum` interface (but you
   can use `DatumState` if you do not
   want well-known type APIs).

No matter your design, I'd recommend the following:

1. Use an "`enum`" or something to tell
   you the "*type*", separate from the
   "*value*".  (I know you can compress
   them into one "`int`" or something
   with bit packing, but that is
   slow-for-access and very tricky to
   maintain as new types are
   introduced.)
2. Lean on templates or something to centralize operations, with a
   mechanism for type-specific
   (override) processing (assuming you want to
   handle non-trivial types).

The name-of-the-game is *"simplified maintenance when adding new types"* (or at least, it was for me).  Like a good Term Paper, it is a very good idea if you rewrite, rewrite, rewrite, to *hold-or-increase* your functionality as you constantly *remove* the code required to maintain the system (e.g., minimize the effort required to adapt new types to your existing `Variant` infrastructure).

Good luck!

Comment: Interestingly enough, you have implemented your variant class in a very similar way to how I have done it. I'm going to have to do some more research and possibly implement this :) Thank you very much @charley

Comment: I was interested mostly in the actual casting system, so the most relevent part of your post was the `static_cast<>()` as that led me on to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2ay8610.aspx) on msdn which describes runtime type casting in c++. I know I never tagged my question with a language as I thought it would be irrelevant, but that is perfect for what I want. With that I cover all but a few conversions, which are easy to check for and do myself.

Answer (score 1):

Done something similar.

You could add another byte to the "header", indicating the type its really storing.

Example in a C-style programming language:

```
typedef
enum VariantInternalType {
  vtUnassigned = 0;
  vtByte = 1;
  vtCharPtr = 2; // <-- "plain c" string
  vtBool = 3;
  // other supported data types
}

// --> real data
typedef
struct VariantHeader {
  void* Reserved; // <-- your data (byte or void*)
  VariantInternalType VariantInternalType;  
}

// --> hides real data
typedef
  byte[sizeof(VariantHeader)] Variant;

// allocates & assign a byte data type to a variant
Variant ByteToVar(byte value)
{
  VariantHeader MyVariantHeader;
  Variant MyVariant;

  MyVariantHeader.VariantInternalType = VariantInternalType.vtByte;
  MyVariantHeader.Reserved = value;  

  memcpy (&MyVariant, &MyVariantHeader, sizeof(Variant));

  return myVariant;
}

// allocates & assign a char array data type to a variant
Variant CharPtrToVar(char* value)
{
  VariantHeader MyVariantHeader;
  Variant MyVariant;

  MyVariantHeader.VariantInternalType = VariantInternalType.vtByte;
  MyVariantHeader.Reserved = strcpy(value);  

  // copy exposed struct type data to hidden array data
  memcpy(&MyVariant, &MyVariantHeader, sizeof(Variant));

  return myVariant;
}

// deallocs memory for any internal data type
void freeVar(Variant &myVariant)
{
  VariantHeader MyVariantHeader;

  // copy exposed struct type data to hidden array data
  memcpy(&MyVariantHeader, &MyVariant, sizeof(VariantHeader));

  switch (MyVariantHeader.VariantInternalType) {
    case vtCharPtr:
      strfree(MyVariantHeader.reserved);
    break;

    // other types

    default:
    break;
  }

  // copy exposed struct type data to hidden array data
  memcpy(&MyVariant, &MyVariantHeader, sizeof(Variant));
}

bool isVariantType(Variant &thisVariant, VariantInternalType thisType)
{
  VariantHeader MyVariantHeader;

  // copy exposed struct type data to hidden array data
  memcpy(&MyVariantHeader, &MyVariant, sizeof(VariantHeader));

  return (MyVariant.VariantInternalType == thisType);
}

// -------

void main()
{
  Variant myVariantStr = CharPtrToVar("Hello World");
  Variant myVariantByte = ByteToVar(42);

  char* myString = null;
  byte  myByte = 0;

  if isVariantType(myVariantStr, vtCharPtr) {
    myString = VarToCharPtr(myVariantStr);
    // print variant string into screen
  }

  // ...    
}
```

This is only a suggestion, and its not tested.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but I think I'll do some work on it to see if it's feasible to implement. I'm not going to accept this as the answer just yet though :P

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've already done the calculation, but the amount of memory you need for the lookup table isn't *that* much.

If you just need to check if types are compatible, then you need (256*256)/2 bits.  This requires 4k of memory.

If you also need a pointer to a conversion function, then you need (256*256)/2 pointers.  This requires 128k of memory on a 32-bit machine and 256k on a 64-bit machine.  If you're willing to do some low-level address layout, you can probably get that down to 64k on both 32-bit and 64-bit machines.